# I can't run the Xamarin new project with Android emulator on Visual Studio on MAC. But IOS emulator works

Tags: macos, visual-studio, xamarin

```
Synchronizing assemblies...
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(579,2): error ADB1000:  Deployment failed
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(579,2): error ADB1000: Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploymentException: FailedToSynchronizeFastDevAssemblies ---> Mono.AndroidTools.AdbException: secure_mkdirs failed: Permission denied
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(579,2): error ADB1000:   at Mono.AndroidTools.Util.AggregateAsyncResult.CheckError (System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x0002a] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/30/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Mono.AndroidTools/Util/AggregateAsyncResult.cs:72 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(579,2): error ADB1000:   at Mono.AndroidTools.Adb.AdbSyncClient.EndPushSyncItems (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00006] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/30/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Mono.AndroidTools/Adb/AdbSyncClient.cs:1071 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(579,2): error ADB1000:   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbClientTaskExtensions.InnerInvoke (System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1[TResult] tcs, System.Func`2[T,TResult] endMethod, System.IAsyncResult l) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/30/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Mono.AndroidTools/Internal/AdbClientTaskExtensions.cs:256 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(579,2): error ADB1000: --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(579,2): error ADB1000: 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(579,2): error ADB1000:   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.InstallAssemblies (System.String destinationPath, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x00339] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/30/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Sessions/AndroidDeploySession.cs:614 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(579,2): error ADB1000:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(579,2): error ADB1000:   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.InstallAssemblies (System.String destinationPath, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x003b5] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/30/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Sessions/AndroidDeploySession.cs:622 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(579,2): error ADB1000:   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.FastDevAsync (System.Boolean useExternal) [0x000da] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/30/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Sessions/AndroidDeploySession.cs:514 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(579,2): error ADB1000:   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.RunAsync (System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x004b0] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/30/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Sessions/AndroidDeploySession.cs:229 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(579,2): error ADB1000:   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.RunLoggedAsync (System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x0002f] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/30/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Sessions/AndroidDeploySession.cs:123
```

Done building target "_Upload" in project "testing.Android.csproj" -- FAILED.

Done building project "testing.Android.csproj" -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

Comment: Tried a different Android device?

Comment: Does it work before? Have you tried to add the new device to test like the screenshot. https://imgur.com/dWIgR3t And if it still does work, to repair your SDKs via Tool> SDK Manager.